# recv() returning SOCKET_ERROR

Tags: c++, winsock

Right now I am currently trying to learn winsock, and to do so I'm trying to just send a file over a socket. I have written all of the code, and I got it to partially work, sending only the top part of an image, but now it has just completely stopped working. I have no idea what is causing send and recv to return SOCKET_ERROR.

To be honest, I have no idea what to do. The socket just closes poops itself and I do not know why.

Here is the code I use for recieving the file size, and also the file itself.

```
cout << "Fetching file from server" << endl;

        int nBytes = 4096, nLeft, idx; // I have no idea what this does, ctrl c + ctrl v always works though, maybe this is the problem?
        nLeft = nBytes;
        idx = 0;


        while (nLeft > 0)

        {
            ret = recv(listening, sizef[idx], nLeft, 0);
            if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                WSACleanup();
                return 912;
            }
            nLeft -= ret;
            idx += ret;
        }
```

Here is the code I use for sending the file size and file.

```
int nBytes = 4096, nLeft, idx;
    nLeft = nBytes;
    idx = 0;
    while (nLeft > 0)
    {
        ret = send(clientSocket, &cstr[idx], nLeft, 0);

        if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)

        {
            cerr << "Oops, failed to send, the programmer shit his pants, or the client did";
            return 912;
        }
        nLeft -= ret;
        idx += ret;
    }
```

Now, the intended result of this function is to just receive the file, but it always returns SOCKET_ERROR, on every file I try.

Comment: What does `WSAGetLastError ()` return after `recv` fails?  Error codes should always be checked.

Comment: Provide socket_error info, at least number, debug will be much easier with that.

Comment: The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call.

So I assume that is the problem?

Comment: The `recv()` code is not accounting for the possibility of `ret` being set to 0 on graceful disconnect.  And it is not calling `closesocket()` before calling `WSACleanup()`. And what is `sizef` declared as? The `recv()` code will not compile unless `sizef` is an array of pointers. If it is just an array of bytes, you need `&sizef[idx]` instead, just like `&cstr[idx]` in the `send()` code.

Comment: sizef is declared as a ``char*``, or array of pointers,  not the old fashion ``char``, an array as bytes, should I be using ``char`` and adding & when calling it in``recv()``?

Comment: @DyeitTye That seems kind of puzzling. If `sizef` is an array of pointers, then if you receive two bytes at the same time, you write them both to the address pointed to by the first pointer, but if you receive one then the other, you write one to the first pointer and one to the second pointer. That seems kind of puzzling. What does the second pointer point to? Do you have multiple buffers the array holds pointers to or what?

Comment: The pointer is simply there to receive a string, ``sizef`` is there to hold the size of the file I will be receiving momentarially. I am using a different `char` to hold the file and eventually write it. The second pointer, `&cstr` I assume you are talking about, just points to a cstr, the size of the file I will be sending.

Comment: Weird. You said `sizef` wqas a `char*`. Can you show us some more code so we can understand what `sizef` really is?

Comment: Sure, here is some more code that might help you, there was just one time I called `sizef` before recv that I didn't call(btw I got the relevant part of `sizef` to work), and that code is....
`char sizef[4096];`
does that help?

Comment: @DyeitTye So, `sizef` is an array of `char`. So `sizef[idx]` is a `char`. So you're passing a `char` to `recv` when you're supposed to pass it a pointer to where you want the received data stored. That will definitely produce an error because the value a `char` can hold is way too small to be a valid pointer.